# What is this chord used in C Major?

Tags: theory

[image]

What is this chord? The key is C Major and I've put in the root (CEG) and the dominant (GBD) as a contrast. It sounds harmonious to me. It's not a V of V (applied/secondary dominant) as that would have D-F#-A but the bass note is G following in pitch with F, B, G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G7:  the dominant seventh chord of C major.

Comment: G7 is G-B-D-F but there's no D in the chord

Comment: The fifth can be omitted in a seventh chord.